# Parse a JSON file in Java

Tags: java, json, hash-map

I am using Java to parse a JSON file into a hash map so that i can search by typing a date and then get the cost, tax and profit for that date.

So that if i write:

```
2001-09-18 13:11:01
```

I get:

```
7.14, 1.81 and 31.10
```

Here is part of the JSON file:

```
{  
  "stat":[  
    {  
      "date":" 2001-09-18 13:11:01 ",
      "cost":" 7.14 ",
      "tax":" 1.81 ",
      "profit":" 31.10 "
    },
    {  
      "date":" 2001-09-18 14:15:02 ",
      "cost":" 7.80 ",
      "tax":" 0.99 ",
      "profit":" 30.20 "
    }
  ]
}
```

And my code using Jackson:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("test.json"));    
            JSONArray jsons = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("stat");
            Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> jsonmaps = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
            int i=0;
            for (Object j : jsons) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject o = (JSONObject) j;
                map = mapper.readValue(j.toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                });
                jsonmaps.put(i, map);
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(jsonmaps.get(0).get("date"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Was something specific you were hoping to get from a review?

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of a `map` variable is not used, you can avoid this assignment and inline the variable. `o` is not used too.

If indexes in a map is consequent then it is better to use a `List` instead of `Map`. So the part of the code can be rewritten following way:

```
List<Map<String, String>> jsonmaps = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object j : jsons) {
    jsonmaps.add(mapper.readValue(j.toString(),
        new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a POJO, your code could be reduced to:

```
public class Stats {
    public List<Stat> stat;
}

public class Stat {
    public String date;
    public Double cost;
    public Double tax;
    public Double profit;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        Stats stats = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), Stats.class);
        System.out.println(stats.stat.get(0).date);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: storing a date in a `String` is generally a bad idea, especially since the stats are looked up by their date, which means your code can result in significant lookup time increases ... The POJO is a good idea, though. A `Map<Date, Stat>` is easily creatable from the list you have there

Comment: @Vogel612 I agree, state.date should be stored in LocalDateTime instead of String, thanks for the feedback.